# How can I change a part of colour scheme?

Tags: vim, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Here is my color scheme setting in `.vimrc`

" Use the Solarized Dark theme
set background=dark
" set background=light
colorscheme solarized
let g:solarized_termtrans=1

It looks like this in `Terminal` on OSX.

[image]

The problem with this scheme is that the cursor is invisible. How can make the cursor visible again?

Similarly in `markdown` files, for the currently selected line the color scheme is blue on black, which make it rather hard to read. How can i change this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Cursor` highlight group to recolor the cursor:

```
:highlight Cursor ctermfg={color} ctermbg={color} cterm={attributes}
```

To see what values can be placed in the `{color}` and `{attributes}` section, read this article in vim:

```
:help highlight-args
```